# Ошибка установки расширения Chrome после упаковки и размещения в Chrome Store

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension, chrome-app, manifest

Написал расширение для Chrome. В разпакованом виде работает как нужно. После упаковки средствами самого Google Chrome и модерации в Chrome Store, не хочет устанавливаться [Ссылка на расширение в chrome store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hdrezka-checker/pmbikimkhiglipegjaljdkcpknoonhgj). Выдаёт ошибку при установке.

[image: Скриншот ошибки]

Пытался гуглить, но ничего не нашёл.
Вот манифест расширения:

```
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "HDRezka checker",
"description": "Расширение для проверки наличия новых серий ваших сериалов на сайте hdrezka.ag",
"version": "1.0.4",

"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "logo.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},

"background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },

"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>",
    "notifications",
    "background",
    "file://*/*",
    "http://*/",
    "https://*/",
    "storage",
    "unlimitedStorage"
]
```

В чём проблема?

Манифест ковырял как мог, разбирал манифесты от других расширений, пробовал разные варианты. Я не вижу проблемы, но скорее всего проблема именно в манифесте.

Comment: Скорее всего проблема не в манифесте а в background.html. Можете показать содержимое?

Comment: Там только подключение js скриптов. А поскольку в розпакованом виде всё работает, крайне маловероятно, что с background.html что-то не так. Кроме того, ранее этого файла вообще не было, js файлы были подключены напрямую в манифесте, была аналогичная ошибка, только он мне говорил о том, что невозможно загрузить jquery.min.js, который был первым в списке подключаемых файлов. Jquery.min.js файл находится локально.

Comment: А jQuery упакована вместе со сборкой?

Comment: Да, я даже пустой background.html пробовал подключать, тот же результат. Уверен проблема в манифесте, просто я её не вижу

Comment: манифест полностью валиден, при условии что все файлы существуют

Comment: Все файлы существуют. Сегодня поэксперементирую ещё, может что-то выясню